# Apollo Server: Create subscription resolver from Observable

Tags: rxjs, graphql-js, apollo-server

In Apollo Server it looks like you have to an AsyncIterator for subscription resolvers:

```
const rootResolver = {
    Query: () => { ... },
    Mutation: () => { ... },
    Subscription: {
        commentAdded: {
          subscribe: () => pubsub.asyncIterator('commentAdded')
        }
    },
};
```

[Source](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/features/subscriptions.html#Subscriptions-Example)

I'm wondering if there is any way to use an RXJS Observable instead or somehow convert it to an AsyncIterator?